# Why a linear transformation from $T:\mathbb C^8\to \mathbb C^5$ is not one one.

Tags: linear-algebra

Why a linear transformation from $T:\mathbb C^8\to \mathbb C^5$ is not one one.

My try:I can solve it if it would be like  $T:\mathbb R^8\to \mathbb R^5$.But I am confused in this.

Comment: You should use the rank nullity theorem. This will tell you that if it were injective, the the kernel is empty, so has dimension zero. From the domain and codomain, you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Because then $W = T(\mathbb{C}^8)$ would be an eight-dimensional subspace of the five-dimensional space $V = \mathbb{C}^5$, which is impossible (assuming your base field is $\mathbb{C}$). Moreover, you wanted to restrict your base field to the real numbers, you could regard $\mathbb{C}^8 \cong \mathbb{R}^{16}$ and $\mathbb{C}^5 \cong \mathbb{R}^{10}$. The transformation $T$ would still be a linear transformation of these real spaces.

Comment: If it is one-to-one, the source has dimension at most the codomain dimension.

Comment: This also mirrors a similar statement for finite sets, with "dimension" standing in for "cardinality": If $|A| > |B|$, then there is no injection from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: The kernel of a linear transformation always contains the null vector.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see that a linear transformation in finite dimensional vector spaces is to write the linear transformation as a matrix vector product.  In other words, we can find a matrix $A$ of dimensions $5\times 8$ so that
$$
T(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}.
$$
The linear transformation is one-to-one if every column of $A$ has a pivot after reduced to row echelon form.  Since there are $8$ columns and only $5$ rows, this is impossible.  More precisely, each row has at most one pivot, this gives the maximum number of pivots as $5$, so it is not possible for there to be a pivot in all $8$ columns.

This construction is independent of the field ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), it just depends on the dimensions of the spaces of interest.